# I dont quite understand why my wcin isn't clearing?

Tags: c++, cin

When I am running this while loop, my initial cin works as intended( I have other checks if keyword equals some other command at the moment), but what I don't quite understand is why my wcin doesn't update after it's first pass through the while loop.

For example, I have my program able to find any file you type in including it's file type extension and works as intended in it's first and is able to only open it right now.

But, if i try to search for another file, it will just re-open another application of the first file ran in the first pass. I looked up a few techniques, using wcin.ignore() and wcin.clear(), but am not making any progress. If someone could help explain 1) why this is happening, and 2) point me in the direction of possible solutions for me to look up and explore on my own I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks everyone

To help people better understand my issue, here is a link to my command line when I initially open "Text1.txt" and then retry the same program and open file "Diego.txt" but it just re-opens "Text1.txt" again.

[image: Single Run Through Of Program]

```
while(runZooey == true)
{
    cin >> keyWord;

    if(keyWord == "ff")
    {
        wstring fileSearchString;
        cout << "Please type in a file that you would like me to open" << endl;
        wcin >> fileSearchString;

        std::clock_t start;
        double duration;

        start = std::clock();

        for (int m = 0; m <= 25; m++)
        {
            if (availableDrives[m] != L"\0" && foundFilePath == L"") 
            {
                std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                std::wcout << "Searching Drive: " << availableDrives[m] << endl;
                std::wcout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                findFile(availableDrives[m] + L":", fileSearchString);
                cout << "Comparisons: " << bruteForceComp << endl;
                std::wcout << "Path is: " << foundFilePath << endl;
            }
        }

        duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        std::cout << "Total Time: " << duration << '\n';
        loadApplication(foundFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `keyWord`? Why are you mixing narrow and wide character input/output? And most importantly, you are aware of that input from either `std::cin` or `std::wcin` is *buffered* and that each object have their *own* buffers? Please stick to one or the other (narrow or wide), and if that doesn't help you then please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, together with input and actual and expected output.

Comment: Keyword is a string, and the reason why I'm using cin and wcin is because I was having difficulty understanding on my first try (when the wcin was a cin and It wasnt working). I then tried using a different one (the wcin) since at the time it made things clearer to differentiate in the program.